# ImportError: No module named robotparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to run a script but for some reasons I have this error showing up

```
scrapy crawl crawler -a url=https://www.montresmecaniques.com/ -o out.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 145, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 267, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 347, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 73, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/dylanuzan/Desktop/scripts/calcul-pagerank-raisonnable/crawl/crawl/spiders/crawler.py", line 6, in <module>
    import urllib.robotparser
ImportError: No module named robotparser
```

I did an alias in my .zsh so when im typing python --version its printing :

Python 3.8.3

But still, we can see that scrapy is launching 2.7 I really don't know how those things decides to be linked & worked together any help please ? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Use `python -m scrapy crawl ...`

Comment: hey thanks, its weird now its saying /usr/local/bin/python3: No module named scrapy but when I do which scrapy i do have a path : usr/local/bin/scrapy

Comment: How did you install scrapy? Did you use `python -m pip install scrapy`?

Comment: Its solve my problem thanks mate I'll try other stuff and see if its working